# If $f,g:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ are linear then there is a linear homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Suppose that$f,g:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ are linear injective maps. I want to show that there is a homotopy $H$ between them such that $H_t$ is also linear and invective for every $t$.

The obvious choice seems to be a straight line homotopy. But it seems this need not be invective since $H_t(x)=f(x)(1-t)+g(x)t$ could be zero if $f(x)$ is a scalar multiple of $g(x)$.

This problem seems fixable, since if $f$ was entirely a multple of $g$ the homotopy would be very easy to make. But i am not sure how to deal will that fact that $f$ could be a multple of $g$ for some $x$ and not for other $x$.

Comment: When you say $\Bbb R^\infty$, what exactly do you mean? There are two commonly used sets that that could refer to: one basically without restrictions, and one where only finitely many entries are non-zero.

Comment: I think I am working with the restricted case. Is the result true for the unrestricted case?

Comment: Yes, it is. But one needs to take a bit more care in constructing the homotopy. The answer below does it nicely.

Comment: For completeness sake of this post for future readers could you provide the argument or possibly a sketch?

Answer (score 2):

$U=Im(f)+Im(g)$ is finite dimensional, we can find vectors $f_N,f_{N+1},.....$ which are not contained in $U$ and such that $f_N,f_{N+1},...,$ are linearly independent.

Define $h_t(e_i)=tf(e_i)+(1-t)g(e_i)+t(t-1)f_{N+i}$